# Translating formula from excel to java

Tags: java, exponent

I'd like to translate these formula in java:

```
=100*((0.1/G10)+1)*EXP(-0.1/G10)
```

Where my G10 is my spacing1. I did it these way:

```
Double rqd1, rqd2, rqd3;

rqd1 = (0.1 / spacing1 + 1) * 100;
rqd2 = Math.exp (-0.1 / spacing1);
rqd3 = rqd1 * rqd2;
```

rqd3 will be the answer. Am I doing it the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
rqd1 = (0.1 / spacing1 + 1) * 100 * Math.exp (-0.1 / spacing1);
```